# Recalculate cropdetect parameters from initial values

Tags: math, ffmpeg, crop

I have a video that is 1920x1080, and cropdetect works great for this static size. My problem is that I am developing for the web, and I want to be able to re-calculate the best crop parameters when the window/video is resized.

Cropping the video, and running cropdetect each time the window is resized seems like overkill. Is there a way to do it from the initial cropdetect values and the resized video width+height?

Comment: Store the cropdetect values in normalized units: 480 would correspond to 480/1920 = 0.25. Then  calculate the actual pixel value based on that after resizing.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example? Let's say the cropdetect params are 1648:1072:136:4 from a video that is 1920:1080. How would I work this out if the video was 480:270?